# Converting Django bytestring in template

Tags: django, character-encoding, django-templates

I have some intl characters in a field that django is returning as a bytestring  - how can I convert it back for display in my template?

EDIT for clarification:
I have some japanese text in bytestring in my db:

'\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x90\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xbc \xe3\x83\x9d\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xbc'

I'd like to convert it back to 
プライバシー ポリシー"

(Note: Django didn't save it in my db this way - the data was imported.)

Comment: What does this mean? Why can't you display a bytestring? Anyway, Django uses unicode exclusively internally, so if you're getting bytetrings somehow it's due to your own misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That text works fine for me in the shell:

```
>>> from django import template
>>> s = '\xe3\x83\x97\xe3\x83\xa9\xe3\x82\xa4\xe3\x83\x90\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xbc \xe3\x83\x9d\xe3\x83\xaa\xe3\x82\xb7\xe3\x83\xbc'
>>> t = template.Template('{{ s }}')
>>> print t.render(template.Context({'s': s}))
プライバシー ポリシー
```

so I'm not sure where you're having problems.

Comment: You're right - there's a problem with the encoding of the string in my db - it's returning some mixture of hex escaped characters and unicode escaped characters